# what is 'primary key' in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, primary-key

i read the article that states "By default, all the models in RoR has a column called id of the type :primary_key."

so i checked the schema file of my c9 project, but i found that automatically created objects are only

```
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
```

According to the above article,

where is t.primary_key "id", null:false ??

im just a beginner, so somebody please help me. 
it would be really thankful if example which is easily understandable to be added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary key will not be there in schema, but what rails does is it will implicitly add a primary key column whenever a new table is created. This happens when you migrate the ruby files for the models. For more info [check this link](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html).

If you are beginner, I suggest you through [Rails Guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/index.html) thoroughly if you can.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Active Record will use an integer column named id as the table's primary key. When using Active Record Migrations to create your tables, this column will be automatically created.

This will help you for more understanding: [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)